# How to $http.post with payload in data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

How do I post data from a form in AngularJS?

```html
<form data-ng-submit="doSomething()">
    <input type="text" data-ng-input="do_obj.text"/>
    <input type="email" data-ng-input="do_obj.email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Do something"/>
</form>
```

```js
$scope.doSomething = function () {
        $http({url: '/api/oauth2/register', method: 'POST', data: $scope.do_obj}
        ).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   $log.info("data = ", data, "status = ", status,
                             "headers = ", headers, "config = ", config);
               }
        );
};
```

[Plnkr (bootstrap styled)](http://plnkr.co/edit/40nkCR1wpF3wFdBXHfgW?p=preview)

Comment: Damn, after all that and it was just a bug with WebStorm. Serving my site over nginx without error >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See plunker code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HTaKAeNYyMmoeFNBVOzl?p=preview)

Changed data-ng-input into data-ng-model and updated data-ng-submit to pass in the model into the scope controller for processing.

HTML:

```
<body data-ng-app>
        <div data-ng-controller="DoCtrl" class="container" style="margin: 15px">
            <form data-ng-submit="doSomething(do_obj)" role="form" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="do_obj.bar"
                           placeholder="Enter text"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-group" type="email"
                           data-ng-model="do_obj.email"
                           placeholder="Enter email"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"
                           data-ng-class="{'btn-info': hover}"
                           data-ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
                           data-ng-mouseleave="hover = false"
                           value="Do something"
                            />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The syntax for posting is $http.post({url}, {payload});.  I have updated your controller function to take in a parameter to pass to the post.

Controller code:

```
function DoCtrl($scope, $http, $log) {
    $log.info("In DoCtrl");
    $scope.do_obj = {};
    $scope.doSomething = function (data) {
      $http.post('/api/oauth2/register', data)
        .success(function(successData){
          console.log(successData);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Whoops, typo on the `ng-input` side. As for the `$http` side, I thought I could send it as a 'data' object…

Comment: You can send it as a data object.  In the controller post method, you can send it as  $http.post('/api/oauth2/register', {data:data}) instead.

Comment: Okay, so shouldn't that work with the more general `$http({})` syntax?